# git stash save -u and -p

Tags: git

I'm trying to split up one commit into five commits. My plan was to use `git stash save -p` and stash everything except what I want in the first commit. Then commit the changes, `git stash apply`, stash everything except what I want in the second commit, etc. Yet my original commit contains newly added files, and it appears that I can't select what I want to stash using -p and also stash untracked files using -u at the same time.

```
$ git stash save -u -p "take 4"
Can't use --patch and --include-untracked or --all at the same time
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a textbook use case for `git add -p`.

Do the following:

- Check out the commit you want to split up.
- `git reset HEAD~`. This will "undo" the commit without losing its changes. They will be in the working tree, unstaged.
- Five times:

  - `git add -p` (and add the changes you want in this "phase"). You'll need to `git add` any files which were added in the original commit, when you come to the patch you want them to be part of.
  - Optionally, `git diff --staged` to see what you're about to commit and/or `git diff` to see what you're *not* about to commit.
  - `git commit`

This will give you five separate commits. You may alternatively use `git add -i` instead of `git add -p`. This use case is not an intended one for `git stash`.

The way this works is by making use of Git's "staging area" (also called "the index"). You have a mess of changes in your working copy. You use `git add` to "stage" the changes. Then `git commit` (WITHOUT the `-a` flag) will only commit the staged changes.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, `git add -p` is definitely the way to go for the original problem.

Regarding the secondary problem, though:

`Can't use --patch and --include-untracked or --all at the same time`

In my case, I wanted to include some untracked files, but *also* use --patch to pick some tracked stuff to stash.  Let's call the combination of these "diff A".  What I did was do the inverse set first: stash away the code that didn't belong to diff A, and that cleared the way to use `git add the_untracked_file` and then `git stash push` to get both tracked and untracked stuff into one stash.